# Does Daedalus perform tasks beyond those of a wallet?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, daedalus, network

I didn't read the user agreement and just installed. Why does it use a full core 100% of the time?

Is it doing work for the health of the network, or any other type of work besides just being my wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. It's a ***cardano-node*** wallet's component, who is guilty for excessive CPU usage. There's nothing you can do about it. It consumes over 100% of CPU power, even though Daedalus wallet is a passive full node. With the release of a ***cardano-light-node*** utility, the situation will be dramatically changed for the better.

By the way, the Bitcoin Core full node app consumes approximately 25% of CPU power.

Comment: I got my numbers from ``Activity Monitor`` which I only quote when I need a program that approaches metrics with a white-hot spotlight, exacerbating their performance flaws. But I confirmed it in `htop` There really is a thread pegged at full load, while three or four other threads dance between not much and 60%.

Watch it in non-threaded mode and the CPU time used for the Wallet moves faster than a normal clock. I can't afford to flight the beta anymore.